# How to present a progress screen before/while a long running operation starts?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am well aware that blocking the UI is not a good idea in general but there are some scenarios where my app simply cannot do any other work until some long running operations (e.g. loading data from a server) are complete.

Assume the user clicks the "Load Data" button. To indicate that no UI interaction is possible until the data is loaded I would like to grey out the screen and show some kind of activity indicator. This is no problem at all, I simply overlay the screen with a new Fragment.

The question is: How can I present this overlay fragment?

```
public void onLoadDataClick() {
    // grey out the screen by simple showing a new Fragment
    showActivityIndicatorOverlay();

    // Start the long running opeartion
    doVeryMuchWork();

    dismissActivityIndicatorOverlay();
}

public void showActivityIndicatorOverlay() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ActivityIndicatorOverlayFragment overlayFragment = ActivityIndicatorOverlayFragment.newInstance("Loading Data");        
    overlayFragment.show(ft, "activityIndicator");
}
```

**This does NOT work.** The overlay does not show up. If I remove `dismissActivityIndicatorOverlay()` the overlay shows up **after** the long running operation completed. This is not too suprising: I assume that the showing the new fragment is handeled at the end of the current run-loop or at the start of the next loop. Of course the long running operation has to complete before the run-loop ends and thus the overlay is displayed too late...

The obvious solution is of course to run the operation in a background thread using an `AsyncTask`:

```
public void onLoadDataClick() {
    LoadDataTask loadTask = new LoadDataTask();
    loadTask.execute();
}

private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showActivityIndicatorOverlay();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        doVeryMuchWork();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        dismissActivityIndicatorOverlay();
    }
}
```

I was surprised, that **this solution doesn't work either.** It behaves exactly like the first approach: The overlay does not appear. When `onPostExecute()` is removed the overlay appears after the operation is complete. the Why is that?

What is the correct solution to present such an activity indicator?

Comment: i think the best way is use of `ProgressBar` for your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the use of a `ProgessDialog`.

Declare a ProgressDialog as an instance variable. Something like : `ProgressDialog pDialog;`

then inside onCreate() :

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
//The next two methods will ensure that the user is unable to 
//cancel the Progress Dialog unless you explicitly 
//do so by calling `pDialog.dismiss();`
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Modify AsyncTask somewhat like this :

```
private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data.. Please Wait.");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        doVeryMuchWork();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that there is some kind of problem with my overlay fragment. When using `ProgressDialog` instead everything works fine. This answer is great but Aniruddha was a little faster, so I accepted his...

Comment: @AndreiHerford I guess it's not that important, but _check the edit history in Aniruddha's post_. He basically answered something completely different and then changed his answer. Shivam was still about half a minute quicker than me, though :)

Comment: All right, all right. I changed the accepted answer and hope that every one is fine with that :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: @matiash Half a minute! :D

Comment: Though I don't have any upvote :D @matiash I also explained how to call the AsyncTask and about the `context`, which you did not.!

Answer (score 1):

A `ProgressDialog` is very much the canonical solution for these cases...

```
private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgress.setTitle("So much to do");
        mProgress.setMessage("Doing very much work");
        mProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        doVeryMuchWork();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        mProgress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

As for your attempted solutions, the first one does not work for the very reasons you state. The second *should*, though.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that there is some kind of problem with my overlay fragment. When using `ProgressDialog` instead everything works fine. This answer is great but Aniruddha was a little faster, so I accepted his...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, if you're not doing heavy stuff precisely on setContentView(R.layout.main)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    handler = new Handler();

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Do some heavy stuff
            return null;
        } 

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result){
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                 @Override
                 public void run(){
                     setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 }
            });
        }
   }.execute();
}
```

**OR you can use progress dialog**

```
private class LongTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private ProgressDialog pd;
Context context;

public LongTask(Context c)
{

     this.context = c;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setTitle("Please wait...!");
    pd.setMessage("Loding the information");
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // do your heavy tasks here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
    if (pd.isShowing())
     pd.dismiss();
}
```

}

Call AsyncTask like this

```
new LongTask(your_activity.this).execute();
```

Comment: Using `setContentView()` multiple times is not the best idea but well android doesnt stop you from doing so ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that there is some kind of problem with my overlay fragment. When using `ProgressDialog` instead everything works fine...